# Main Ui Thread does not update during method procedure

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface, android-imageview

i am new to android sdk so pls don't be to harsh on me. atm i am on my first android app .. its almost done but i am facing a little problem right now.

the app is a small single player cardplay game with 4 players - 3 computer enemys.

the problem is that after i do a move .. the computer enemys are doing their moves based on ki logic .. and that is working just fine .. but only the last move of lets say player 4 is shown after the end of method. even if i delay the method procedure after each ki move .. it doesn't update the ImageViews to show the current ki move ...

im really pretty lost .. as i can't find any logic mistake .. i appreciate any kind of help .. thx for reading - not native English speaker sry for that :-)

Ok here goes some code .. cardDeck holds the current move

```
List<Card> cardDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();
List<Card> move = new ArrayList<Card>();
KI player2 = new KI();

but.setText("GO");
but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View vw) {

 if (!move.isEmpty()) {

    if (Rules.checkIsPlayableHand(move)) {
    sort();
    setClickAble();
        ki4Moves(vw);   
    }
```

sort() looks kind of this:

```
public void sort(){

   cardDeck.clear();
   cardDeck.addAll(move);

    if (cardDeck.size() == 1) {
        dkView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dkView1);
        Card card = cardDeck.get(0);
        dkView1.setImageBitmap(card.getBitmap());
    } else {
        dkView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dkView1);
        dkView1.setImageBitmap(blank);
    }
}
```

and ki4Moves() looks kind of this:

```
public void ki4Moves(View vw){

   player2.think();
   List<Card> kiMove = new ArrayList<Card>();
   kiMove = player2.getPossibleMove(cardDeck);

    if (!kiMove.isEmpty()) {

        trash.addAll(kiMove);
        move.clear();
        move.addAll(kiMove);
        sort();
   }
   // same for the other both ki s
}
```

EDIT:

well after some research .. reading android docs i havent found a real solution for my problem.

WHAT I WANTED TO DO IS : FORCE THE MAIN UI THREAD TO UPDATE AFTER SORT() .. LIKE THIS:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View vw) {

 if (!move.isEmpty()) {

    if (Rules.checkIsPlayableHand(move)) {
    sort();
            // FORCE MAIN UI THREAD TO UPDATE .. just one line 
            // let SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    setClickAble();
        ki4Moves(vw);   
    }
```

Now .. that i cant force the main thread to update or access it outside of the main thread  .. ANDROID offers me Threading, Painless Threading, Async Task .. wow thanks for THAT!

1. the procedure is not heavy loaded ... no database operations etc.
2. if i use thread.join ... main ui thread is still locked

So first of all .. i dont see any logical reason to use threads .. BUT I KINDA HAVE TO ? so okay here i go .. lets say i change my code like this:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
@Override
public void onClick(View vw) {

 if (!move.isEmpty()) {

    if (Rules.checkIsPlayableHand(move)) {

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable){

                void run(){
                h.post(new Runnable(){
                    // do some logic here
                });
                h.post(new Runnable(){
                   if (cardDeck.size() == 1) {
               dkView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dkView1);
           Card card = cardDeck.get(0);
           dkView1.setImageBitmap(card.getBitmap());
               } else {
           dkView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dkView1);
           dkView1.setImageBitmap(blank);
               }
                });
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            });
            t.start();

    setClickAble();
        ki4Moves(vw);   
    }
```

So ye this is working fine .. BUT oh .. there is this method "ki4Moves(vw)" ... i cant let it t.join() .. cause as i said the main ui thread is gonna be locked. so i need to WRAP the 200 lines out of ki4Moves into threads aswell ..

and ye this is working .. after every move .. the main ui is updated.

BUUUT ki4Moves is one of the easiest methods .. what about if i pass the move .. and the cpu players go into a loop to finish it.. i cant hierachly access the main ui in this loop .. so there i am again.

I dont get it .. it took me like 2 weeks to implement the logic .. as the rules of this game are pretty special .. and now that it is running as intended, ki is smart .. it fails cause of the UI LOCKS UP .. shame on this ..

Comment: Show us some code.... and are you using invalidate() at image view?

Comment: i added some code .. and no i am not using invalidate()

Answer (score 0):

The code looks kind complex to me, but if I understood well, calling invalidate() on dkView1 after setImageBitmap() would solve the problem.

But here is a tip, try to use drawable instead of Bitmap if possible.

Comment: i wished invalidate would have solved the problem but it did not ..:-( .. i only use 1 main frame and the ImageViews and buttons in it .. its like the frame freezes during the procedure and show up the last information as procedure is done ... i will take a look at drawable doc .. thx for caring tho

Comment: Well, if it is freezing during procedure it may be too heavy and should be placed in an AsyncTask... and than call setImageBitmap() using a Handler created at UI thread.